# How to remove specific rows from a 2D array if an element in that row does not meet certain conditions?

Tags: python, arrays

My program takes a table off of a website and creates a 2D array for me. I want to get rid of the useless rows in the table (that contain elements like "August") but do not know what specific conditions I can set to only get rid of those rows. Here is an example of what the array looks like. The code to replicate the whole table is below:

[Console log printing the 2d array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWzFu.png)

The code to replicate the above array:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.islamicfinder.org/world/united-states/5350937/fresno-prayer-times/'

monthlyPrayers = pd.read_html(url)

print(monthlyPrayers[0])
```

If anyone could suggest a method to remove only the rows containing those random words and not the rows containing dates or times, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep the header and get rid only of rows after that -> they have some NaNs, so just `monthlyPrayers[0].dropna()` will work

But this is more elegant I guess:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://www.islamicfinder.org/world/united-states/5350937/fresno-prayer-times/'

monthlyPrayers = pd.read_html(url)

for i in range(0, len(monthlyPrayers[0])):
    try:
        int(monthlyPrayers[0][0][i])
    except TypeError:
        monthlyPrayers[0][0][i] = np.nan

monthlyPrayers[0].dropna(inplace=True)
```